# Exif data for camera trapping image management. Creating new names for images based on date-time and folder names

Tags: r, image, function, loops, exif

I am sorry for my stupid questions but I am struggling to write the code I want. I am working with code found on the blogpost: Fish and Whistle by Dewey Dunnington (http://apps.fishandwhistle.net/archives/956).

I am trying to write a loop where I can rename all images in all folders (recursively) with the name of the folders and the "CreateDate" date-time from the EXIF data. Images are stored in camera station (e.g. Station "A") folders and then in camera folders (2 cameras at a station e.g. Camera "1").

So an individual image directory would be: 
H:/GitHub/CT_Mara/images/raw_images/A/1/....jpg....jpg....jpg....etc.

So, ideally, I would want my images renamed to "A1_2017-05-03 15-45-13.jpg" and if there are two or more photos with the same name they should be called: "A1_2017-05-03 15-45-13(1).jpg" and "A1_2017-05-03 15-45-13(2).jpg"

## What I am trying to accomplish:

1. rename all images according to the date and time in
   exifdata$CreateDate
2. attach (1), (2), etc to images with the same name
3. attach the name of the station and camera folders to the image's
   name
4. then lastly, as a separate function, it would be nice to know how I
   could create a new coulomb in the exifdata frame for example a
   "species" coulomb where animals can be identified

This is the code I am using:

```
library(lubridate)
```

## define exif function

```
exifRip <- function(filename) {
  command <- paste("exiftool -n -csv",
                   paste(shQuote(filename), collapse=" "))
  read.csv(textConnection(system(command, intern=TRUE)),
           header = TRUE,
           sep = ",",
           quote = "",
           stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

## load exif data from my directory

```
exifdata <- exifRip(list.files(path="H:/GitHub/CT_Mara/images/raw_images"))
View(exifdata)
```

## set output directory

```
outdir <- dir.create("H:/GitHub/CT_Mara/images/raw_images/EXIFdata")
```

## Everything runs perfect except for this loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(exifdata)) {
  row <- exifdata[i, ]
  d <- ymd_hms(row$CreateDate)
  ext <- tools::file_ext(row$SourceFile) #maintain file extension
  newname <- file.path(outdir,
                       sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d.%02d.%02d.%s",
                               year(d), month(d), day(d), hour(d), minute(d),
                               second(d), ext))
  file.copy(row$SourceFile, newname)
}
```

## I get the following error message:

```
Error in sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d %02d.%02d.%02d.%s", year(d), month(d),  : 
  invalid format '%04d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
In addition: Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Any advice on how to clean this up would be highly appreciated.. Thanks in advance.

Kind Regards,
Philip

Comment: The problem seems to come from `lubridate::ymd_hms`, probably because the date in row$CreateDate is not in the correct format. You probably need to include `dput(head(exifdata))` but also check `i` to see if the loop failed on the first iteration or worked for some rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following exiftool command gives you almost exactly what you want without the need to write a script.  The only difference is that duplicate files will be named like "NAME_1", "NAME_2" instead of "NAME(1)", "NAME(2)":

```
exiftool '-filename<%-1:1D%-1:D_${createdate}%+c.%e' -d "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S" -r DIR
```

Where DIR is the name of the directory containing the images.  If you are in Windows, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes around the first argument.

Replace "filename" with "testname" in this command for a dry-run test to see what the file names will be before actually doing the renaming.